# Cheerio: Select values of multiple inputs

Tags: jquery-selectors, cheerio, html-input

I have a table of inputs like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input value="Jill" /></td>
    <td><input value="Stein" /></td>
    <td><input value="30" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input value="Eve" /></td>
    <td><input value="Jackson" /></td> 
    <td><input value="94" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Each of these inputs also has a class of "contact-cell".

How can I get these all of these values at once using Cheerio?

If I do `$('.contact-cell').val()` I only get the first input's value `Jill`. I would love to have a result of `'Jill, Stein, 30, Eve, Jackson, 94'`, `'Jill Stein 30 Eve Jackson 94'` or `['Jill', 'Stein', '30', 'Eve', 'Jackson', '94']` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.contact-cell').get().map(input => $(input).attr('value'))
```

The `get()` turns it into an array of js elements

Comment: I used it like this `$('.contact-cell')
        .get()
        .map(input => $(input).val())` because some of the cell's have `<select />`s as an input. It works, thank you very much!